# Error with Java WebStart Signed Jars on 1.7.0_40

Tags: java, classloader, java-web-start, jnlp, jarsigner

We are aware of the issue with jar softlinker
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6967414
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6805618

and have used following class (found on web and modified to take care of JAVA 7 as well.)

---

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.ref.SoftReference;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.JarURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.jar.JarFile;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
 
 
/**
* A utility class for working around the java webstart jar signing/security bug
* <p/>
* see http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6967414 and https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6805618
*
* @author Scott Chan
*/
public class JarSignersHardLinker {
 
 
  private static final String JRE_1_DOT = "1.";
    private static final String DOT_ZERO_UNDERSCORE = ".0_";
 
 
  /**
  * the 1.6.0 update where this problem first occurred
  */
  private static final int PROBLEM_JRE_UPDATE = 19;
 
 
    private static final int PROBLEM_JRE_MAJOR_VERSION = 6;
 
 
  public static final List sm_hardRefs = new ArrayList();
 
 
  protected static void makeHardSignersRef(JarFile jar) throws java.io.IOException {
  if (jar != null && jar.getClass().getName().equals("com.sun.deploy.cache.CachedJarFile")) {
             Logger.info("Making hard refs for: " + jar.getName());
  //lets attempt to get at the each of the soft links.
  //first need to call the relevant no-arg method to ensure that the soft ref is populated
  //then we access the private member, resolve the softlink and throw it in a static list.
  callNoArgMethod("getSigners", jar);
  makeHardLink("signersRef", jar);
  callNoArgMethod("getSignerMap", jar);
  makeHardLink("signerMapRef", jar);
 
 
//            callNoArgMethod("getCodeSources", jar);
//            makeHardLink("codeSourcesRef", jar);
  callNoArgMethod("getCodeSourceCache", jar);
  makeHardLink("codeSourceCacheRef", jar);
 
 
  }
  }
 
 
  /**
  * if the specified field for the given instance is a Softreference
  * That soft reference is resolved and the returned ref is stored in a static list,
  * making it a hard link that should never be garbage collected
  *
  * @param fieldName
  * @param instance
  */
  private static void makeHardLink(String fieldName, Object instance) {
  //System.out.println("attempting hard ref to " + instance.getClass().getName() + "." + fieldName);
  try {
  Field signersRef = instance.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
  signersRef.setAccessible(true);
  Object o = signersRef.get(instance);
  if (o instanceof SoftReference) {
  SoftReference r = (SoftReference) o;
  Object o2 = r.get();
  sm_hardRefs.add(o2);
  } else {
  Logger.warn(fieldName + ": is not an instance of soft reference");
  }
  } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  return;
  } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  }
  }
 
 
  /**
  * Call the given no-arg method on the given instance
  *
  * @param methodName
  * @param instance
  */
  private static void callNoArgMethod(String methodName, Object instance) {
  // System.out.println("calling noarg method hard ref to " + instance.getClass().getName() + "." + methodName + "()");
  try {
  Method m = instance.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methodName);
  m.setAccessible(true);
  m.invoke(instance);
 
 
  } catch (SecurityException e1) {
  e1.printStackTrace();
  } catch (NoSuchMethodException e1) {
  e1.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  }
  }
 
 
  /**
  * is the preloader enabled. ie: will the preloader run in the current environment
  *
  * @return
  */
  public static boolean isHardLinkerEnabled() {
  boolean isHardLinkerDisabled = false;  //change this to use whatever mechanism you use to enable or disable the preloader
  return !isHardLinkerDisabled && isRunningOnJre1_6_0_19OrHigher() && isRunningOnWebstart();
  }
 
 
  /**
  * is the application currently running on webstart
  * <p/>
  * detect the presence of a JNLPclassloader
  *
  * @return
  */
  public static boolean isRunningOnWebstart() {
  ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
  while (cl != null) {
  if (cl.getClass().getName().equals("com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader")) {
  return true;
  }
  cl = cl.getParent();
  }
  return false;
 
 
  }
 
 
  /**
  * Is the JRE 1.6.0_19 or higher?
  * TBFI-5349: Java has a bug, sometimes Jars get garbage collected. To resolve this we are making
     * hard references to the Jars.
     *
     * This method checks for java version. The bug is in 1.6.0_19 and above release hence checking for version 19
  * @return
  */
  public static boolean isRunningOnJre1_6_0_19OrHigher() {
        String javaVersion = System.getProperty("java.version");
 
 
        String updateStr = null;
        String javaMajorVersionStr = null;
        boolean isHardReferenceRequired = false;
 
 
        // Problem persist in JAVA 7 and probable in JAVA 8 as well. So changing the patter.
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(JRE_1_DOT + "([6-9]+)" + DOT_ZERO_UNDERSCORE + "([0-9]+)(.*)");
 
 
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(javaVersion);
 
 
        while (matcher.find()) {
            javaMajorVersionStr = matcher.group(1);
            updateStr = matcher.group(2);
            break;
        }
        Logger.info("Java version: " + javaMajorVersionStr + " update string: " + updateStr);
        try {
            if (javaMajorVersionStr != null) {
 
 
                int java_version = Integer.parseInt(javaMajorVersionStr);
 
 
                if (java_version > PROBLEM_JRE_MAJOR_VERSION) {
                    isHardReferenceRequired = true;
                } else if (java_version == PROBLEM_JRE_MAJOR_VERSION && Integer.parseInt(updateStr) >= PROBLEM_JRE_UPDATE) {
                    isHardReferenceRequired = true;
                }
            }
            return isHardReferenceRequired;
 
 
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            //then unable to determine java Major version or update level
            e.printStackTrace();
            return isHardReferenceRequired;
        }
    }
 
 
  /**
  * get all the JarFile objects for all of the jars in the classpath
  *
  * @return
  */
  public static Set<JarFile> getAllJarsFilesInClassPath() {
  Set<JarFile> jars = new LinkedHashSet<JarFile>();
  for (URL url : getAllJarUrls()) {
  try {
  jars.add(getJarFile(url));
  } catch (IOException e) {
                Logger.error("unable to retrieve jar at URL: " + url);
  }
  }
  return jars;
  }
 
 
  /**
  * Returns set of URLS for the jars in the classpath.
  * URLS will have the protocol of jar eg: jar:http://HOST/PATH/JARNAME.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
  */
  static Set<URL> getAllJarUrls() {
  try {
  Set<URL> urls = new LinkedHashSet<URL>();
  Enumeration<URL> mfUrls = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResources("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
  while (mfUrls.hasMoreElements()) {
  URL jarUrl = mfUrls.nextElement();
//                System.out.println(jarUrl);
  if (!jarUrl.getProtocol().equals("jar")) {
  continue;
  }
  urls.add(jarUrl);
  }
  return urls;
  } catch (IOException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
  }
 
 
  /**
  * get the jarFile object for the given url
  *
  * @param jarUrl
  * @return
  * @throws IOException
  */
  public static JarFile getJarFile(URL jarUrl) throws IOException {
  URLConnection urlConnnection = jarUrl.openConnection();
  if (urlConnnection instanceof JarURLConnection) {
  // Using a JarURLConnection will load the JAR from the cache when using Webstart 1.6
  // In Webstart 1.5, the URL will point to the cached JAR on the local filesystem
  JarURLConnection jcon = (JarURLConnection) urlConnnection;
  return jcon.getJarFile();
  } else {
  throw new AssertionError("Expected JarURLConnection");
  }
  }
 
 
  /**
  * Spawn a new thread to run through each jar in the classpath and create a hardlink
  * to the jars softly referenced signers infomation.
  */
  public static void go() {
  if (!isHardLinkerEnabled()) {
  return;
  }
  Logger.info("Starting Resource Preloader Hardlinker");
  Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
 
 
  public void run() {
  try {
  Set<JarFile> jars = getAllJarsFilesInClassPath();
  for (JarFile jar : jars) {
  makeHardSignersRef(jar);
  }
  } catch (Exception e) {
  Logger.warn("Problem preloading resources", e);
  } catch (Error e) {
                    Logger.error("Error preloading resources", e);
  }
  }
  });
  t.start();
  }
}
```

---

When we launch the application with JRE6 it works fine. But the problem is with JRE7. When the application is launched with JRE7 we get below exception in the log. From the exception we know that the jars are not hard referenced and that the user can have problems if the jars get garbage collected. We have a release next week and need to find a work around for this issue.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.sun.deploy.cache.CachedJarFile.getSigners()
  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Unknown Source)
  at com.XXXXXX.ui.main.JarSignersHardLinker.callNoArgMethod(JarSignersHardLinker.java:96)
  at com.XXXXXX.ui.main.JarSignersHardLinker.makeHardSignersRef(JarSignersHardLinker.java:45)
  at com.XXXXXX.ui.main.JarSignersHardLinker$1.run(JarSignersHardLinker.java:262)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: signersRef
  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Unknown Source)
  at com.XXXXXX.ui.main.JarSignersHardLinker.makeHardLink(JarSignersHardLinker.java:69)
  at com.XXXXXX.ui.main.JarSignersHardLinker.makeHardSignersRef(JarSignersHardLinker.java:46)
  at com.XXXXXX.ui.main.JarSignersHardLinker$1.run(JarSignersHardLinker.java:262)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This exception is repeated 52 times (for all the JAR's).

We have made sure that all the 52 jars/files (except the JNLP itself) are signed properly and that the java cache is cleard before the application is launched.

JAVA version used is JDK 7u40 on windows machine.

Options tried are:

1. Removing the jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, RSA keySize < 1024
   from java.securites file.
2. Checking the jar signer certificate. Signer certificate uses SHA1withRSA as signing algorithm.

Note:

1. THE SOURCE CODE IS COMPILED IN JAVA 5u11 AND RUN IN JAVA 7u40
2. We have observed one more difference. With JRE6, when we run the same
   piece of code, it first loades JAVAWS.jar, Deploy.jar and plugin .jar from java/jre6/lib path but with JRE7 these jars are not loaded.

This has been tried in both 64 and 32 bits java version with no luck.

Any help here is really appreciated.

Comment: Is this the way you sign your jars prior to deploy them?  Have you tried `<jarsign/>` ant task?  This one didn't give me any problems with jdk1.7 up to update 45

Answer (score 0):

@jorge_B: We sign the jars using ant task. But due to a problem in JAVA 6u19 (where the softreferenced jars are sometimes garbage collected) we have decided to hardlink the jars as soon as we hit a java version 6u19 or above. This issue is not with jar signing. The issue is when we try to hard reference the jars. our jars are not getting hard referenced, insted we are getting nosuchmethod and nosuchfield exception in the log.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.ref.SoftReference;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.JarURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.jar.JarFile;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * A utility class for working around the java webstart jar signing/security bug
 * <p/>
 * see http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6967414 and http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6805618
 *
 * @author Scott Chan
 */
public class JarSignersHardLinker {

    private static final String JRE_VERSION_START = "1.";
    private static final int PROBLEM_JRE_VERSION = 6;
    private static final String DOT_ZERO = ".0_";

    /**
     * the 1.6.0 update where this problem first occurred
     */
    private static final int PROBLEM_JRE_UPDATE = 19;
    private static String majorVersionStr = null;
    public static final List sm_hardRefs = new ArrayList();

    protected static void makeHardSignersRef(JarFile jar) throws java.io.IOException {
        Logger.info("Making hard refs for: " + (jar != null ? jar.getName() : null) + " with Java Version: "+majorVersionStr);
        if (jar != null && jar.getClass().getName().equals("com.sun.deploy.cache.CachedJarFile")) {

            //lets attempt to get at the each of the soft links.
            //first neet to call the relevant no-arg method to ensure that the soft ref is populated
            //then we access the private member, resolve the softlink and throw it in a static list.
            if (majorVersionStr != null && Integer.parseInt(majorVersionStr) > PROBLEM_JRE_VERSION) {
                callNoArgMethod("getSigningData", jar);
                makeHardLink("signingDataRef", jar);
            } else {
                callNoArgMethod("getSigners", jar);
                makeHardLink("signersRef", jar);
                callNoArgMethod("getSignerMap", jar);
                makeHardLink("signerMapRef", jar);

//            callNoArgMethod("getCodeSources", jar);
//            makeHardLink("codeSourcesRef", jar);
                callNoArgMethod("getCodeSourceCache", jar);
                makeHardLink("codeSourceCacheRef", jar);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * if the specified field for the given instance is a Softreference
     * That soft reference is resolved and the returned ref is stored in a static list,
     * making it a hard link that should never be garbage collected
     *
     * @param fieldName
     * @param instance
     */
    private static void makeHardLink(String fieldName, Object instance) {
        Logger.info("attempting hard ref to " + instance.getClass().getName() + "." + fieldName);
        try {
            Field signersRef = instance.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
            signersRef.setAccessible(true);
            Object o = signersRef.get(instance);
            if (o instanceof SoftReference) {
                SoftReference r = (SoftReference) o;
                Object o2 = r.get();
                sm_hardRefs.add(o2);
            } else {
                Logger.warn(fieldName + ": is not an instance of soft reference");
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Call the given no-arg method on the given instance
     *
     * @param methodName
     * @param instance
     */
    private static void callNoArgMethod(String methodName, Object instance) {
        Logger.info("calling noarg method hard ref to " + instance.getClass().getName() + "." + methodName + "()");
        try {
            Method m = instance.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methodName);
            m.setAccessible(true);
            m.invoke(instance);

        } catch (SecurityException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * is the preloader enabled. ie: will the preloader run in the current environment
     *
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean isHardLinkerEnabled() {
        boolean isHardLinkerDisabled = false;  //change this to use whatever mechanism you use to enable or disable the preloader
        return !isHardLinkerDisabled && isRunningOnJre1_6_0_19OrHigher() && isRunningOnWebstart();
    }

    /**
     * is the application currently running on webstart
     * <p/>
     * detect the presence of a JNLPclassloader
     *
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean isRunningOnWebstart() {
        ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        while (cl != null) {
            if (cl.getClass().getName().equals("com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader")) {
                return true;
            }
            cl = cl.getParent();
        }
        return false;

    }

    /**
     * Is the JRE 1.6.0_19 or higher?
     *
     * @return
     */

    public static boolean isRunningOnJre1_6_0_19OrHigher() {
        String javaVersion = System.getProperty("java.version");
        // Sometimes java releases version 1.X.0_YY-rev for specific issue and specific user,
        // to resolve this we use patter instead of string split.
        //ERP-6460: Checking whether JRE is 6 update 19 or higher
        String updateStr = null;
        majorVersionStr = null;
        boolean isHardReferenceRequired = false;

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(JRE_VERSION_START + "([6-9]+)" + DOT_ZERO + "([0-9]+)(.*)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(javaVersion);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            majorVersionStr = matcher.group(1);
            updateStr = matcher.group(2);
            break;
        }

        try {
            if (majorVersionStr != null) {
                int java_version = Integer.parseInt(majorVersionStr);
                if (java_version > PROBLEM_JRE_VERSION) {
                    isHardReferenceRequired = true;
                } else if (java_version == PROBLEM_JRE_VERSION && Integer.parseInt(updateStr) >= PROBLEM_JRE_UPDATE) {
                    isHardReferenceRequired = true;
                }
            }
            return isHardReferenceRequired;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return isHardReferenceRequired;
        }
    }

    /**
     * get all the JarFile objects for all of the jars in the classpath
     *
     * @return
     */
    public static Set<JarFile> getAllJarsFilesInClassPath() {
        Set<JarFile> jars = new LinkedHashSet<JarFile>();
        for (URL url : getAllJarUrls()) {
            try {
                jars.add(getJarFile(url));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Logger.error("unable to retrieve jar at URL: " + url);
            }
        }
        return jars;
    }

    /**
     * Returns set of URLS for the jars in the classpath.
     * URLS will have the protocol of jar eg: jar:http://HOST/PATH/JARNAME.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     */
    static Set<URL> getAllJarUrls() {
        try {
            Set<URL> urls = new LinkedHashSet<URL>();
            Enumeration<URL> mfUrls = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResources("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
            while (mfUrls.hasMoreElements()) {
                URL jarUrl = mfUrls.nextElement();
//                System.out.println(jarUrl);
                if (!jarUrl.getProtocol().equals("jar")) {
                    continue;
                }
                urls.add(jarUrl);
            }
            return urls;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * get the jarFile object for the given url
     *
     * @param jarUrl
     * @return
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static JarFile getJarFile(URL jarUrl) throws IOException {
        URLConnection urlConnnection = jarUrl.openConnection();
        if (urlConnnection instanceof JarURLConnection) {
            // Using a JarURLConnection will load the JAR from the cache when using Webstart 1.6
            // In Webstart 1.5, the URL will point to the cached JAR on the local filesystem
            JarURLConnection jcon = (JarURLConnection) urlConnnection;
            return jcon.getJarFile();
        } else {
            throw new AssertionError("Expected JarURLConnection");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Spawn a new thread to run through each jar in the classpath and create a hardlink
     * to the jars softly referenced signers infomation.
     */
    public static void go() {
        if (!isHardLinkerEnabled()) {
            return;
        }
        Logger.info("Starting Resource Preloader Hardlinker");
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                try {
                    Set<JarFile> jars = getAllJarsFilesInClassPath();
                    for (JarFile jar : jars) {
                        makeHardSignersRef(jar);
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Logger.error("Problem preloading resources", e);
                } catch (Error e) {
                    Logger.error("Error preloading resources", e);
                }
            }

        });
        t.start();

    }
}
```

Comment: Use the above code to resolve the issue. The cause of the issue is the change in the methods. For JAVA 7u40 and above you can use following methods callNoArgMethod("getSigningData", jar) and              makeHardLink("signingDataRef", jar);

Comment: The above code resolved our problem and all started working fine for us after the above piece of code.